# Where does the third dimension (as in 4x4x4) of tensor cores come from?

Tags: matrix, gpu, cpu-cores, asic

As I understand, the Nvidia tensor cores multiplies two 4x4 matrices and adds the result to a third matrix. Multiplying two 4x4 matrices produces a 4x4 matrix, and adding two 4x4 matrices produces a 4x4 matrix. Still "Each Tensor Core provides a 4x4x4 matrix processing array".

There are 4x multiplication-accumulate operations that are needed for each row*col. I thought maybe the last x4 comes from intermediate result before the accumulation, but I don't think it quite fits with the description on Nvidias pages.

"The FP16 multiply results in a full precision result that is accumulated in FP32 operations with the other products in a given dot product for a 4x4x4 matrix multiply, as Figure 9 shows."
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-9-features-revealed/

4x4x4 matrix multiply? I thought matrices was 2dimensions by definition.

Can someone please explain where the last x4 comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4x4x4 is just the notation for multiplication of one 4x4 matrix with another 4x4 matrix.

If you were to multiply a 4x8 matrix with a 8x4 matrix, you would have 4x8x4. So if A is NxK and B is KxM, then it can be referred to as a NxKxM matrix multiply.

I just briefly looked up and found this paper, where they use this exact notation (e.g. in Section 4.6 on page 36): https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/153863/eth-6705-01.pdf

Comment: Thanks!

I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but ill mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Probably makes more sense in a hardware pipeline than when doing it by hand on paper. Then you normally add things up before you continue to the next. Atleast don't recall seeing it before now.

Answer (score 0):

The cube itself represents the 64 element-wise products required to generate the full 4x4 product matrix" cvw.cac.cornell.edu/GPUarch/tensor_cores. It is the intermediate products before accumulation that make up the last x4.